# Getting error 'cannot call non w3c standard command while in w3c mode'

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

I've been trying to `browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.xpath('some_xpath'))).perform` with protractor to move mouse to the element on page. And geted error when run test on CI\CD. Locally it works fine.
**Chrome version 80**
**chromedriver version 80**

here my protractor.config file where i turn w3c to false

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    platform: 'ANY',
    version: 'ANY',

    //Disable or Enable multiCapabilities
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 8,
    // maxSession: 10,
    splitTestsBetweenCapabilities: true,

    chromeOptions: {
        w3c: false,
        args: [
            'incognito',
            'disable-extensions',
            'disable-infobars',
            // "--headless",
            // "--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--window-size=1920,1080",
            'show-fps-counter=true',
            // '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
            // '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'
            "--auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Entire screen",
            "--aggressive-cache-discard",
            "--disable-cache",
            "--disk-cache-size=0"
        ],
        prefs: {
            download: {
                prompt_for_download: false,
                directory_upgrade: true,
                default_directory: downloadsPath
            }
        }
    }
}],
```

Comment: I also get error on any function browser.actions

Comment: Same error here while my selenium node run with capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, chromeOptions: {w3c: false}, maxInstances: 1, platform: WIN10, platformName: WIN10, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver, server:CONFIG_UUID: ...}